# I am trying to find link from a website but when i get the link it shows link as "#"

Tags: python, web-scraping

Below is the code i am using

```
for link in f:
    

    r = requests.get(link,verify=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')
    soup.encode('utf-8')
    table = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'right'})
    print(table.div.a)
    download = table.div.a['href']
```

Here instead of getting the download link i am getting a "#"

- link i am scraping : https://www54.zippyshare.com/v/2Mu2T2KI/file.html
- Desired output :

`/d/2qeYvgEb/29682/Horizon%20-%20Zero%20Dawn%20CE%20--%20fitgirl-repacks.site%20--.part01.rar`

- Output getting : `#`

Comment: I think the problem is that the link is not in the original html code, but it changes using the html script. If you check the `table` html it contains a javascript script which contains the link.

Comment: The download link for that particular page is actually `href="/d/2Mu2T2KI/39655/fg-selective-english.part1.rar"` is that what you're looking for, OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the link doesn't exist in the original html, but it changes using an js script. To be able to find the link you need to let js run. I do not think that this is possible using `bs4`.

Another way to do it is using `requests-html`:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

root = 'https://www54.zippyshare.com'
link = 'https://www54.zippyshare.com/v/2Mu2T2KI/file.html'

r = session.get(link)
r.html.render()  # this will load js

download_link = root + r.html.find('.right', first=True).find('a', first=True).attrs['href']
```

Note that I used a css selector `.right`; this is the same as `class`: `right`, though the latter is not supported on `requests-html`. The `first=True` argument does the same job as using `find` instead of `find_all` in `bs4`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that requests-html will download pupeteer in the background, and is in fact a less flexible selenium-like solution.

Answer (score 0):

here, all of the link will show in this site

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www54.zippyshare.com/v/2Mu2T2KI/file.html"
r = requests.get(url)
htmlcontent  = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify)


df = soup.find_all("a")
for data in df:
    dx = data.get('href')
    if dx != "#":
        print(dx)
```

**Hope it will help you**